# Compare and count same digits between two numbers

Tags: python

I'm looking to write a function that receives two four-digit numbers (`m`, `n`) that counts how many digits are the same between `m` and `n`, including duplicates and zeroes on the left. The thing is, my professor only taught us how to use loops, and don't want us to use lists and intersections, and I'm no able to do it.

For example, if `m = 331` and `n = 3`, it should return `2` as the amount of equal digits, bit if `n = 33`, it should return 3 same digits.

```
>>> compare_digits(331, 3)
2
>>> compare_digits(332, 33)
3
```

Edit: This is the code I created before, and it counts same digits more than it should, but the central idea is the usage of % and // to read each digit, but it's not working...

```
def compare_digits(m, n):
read_ndigits = 0
same_digits = 0
while read_ndigits < 4:  #number of digits
    current_n = n % 10
    read_mdigits = 0
    while read_mdigits < 4:
        current_m = m % 10
        if current_n == current_m:
            same_digits += 1
        m //= 10
        read_mdigits += 1
    n //= 10
    read_ndigits += 1

return same_digits
```

The output is very messy and I can't even recognize any pattern.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help; without a [mcve] you don't have a question here.

Comment: You should use the `str.zfill` method to compare apples to apples once you get your digits in, then loop over one set of digits and use `in` or `str.count` to check membership.

Comment: I do not understand the task. How is the output `2` and `3`? I see 3 and 4 `3`s respectively.

Comment: @dedObed `331, 3` becomes `0331` and `0003`, and each have one zero and one three in common. `0331 and 0033` have one zero and two threes in common.

Comment: @AdamSmith ah, thanks. Seems weird though. Is there some "practical" problem that reduces to this?

Comment: Ehhhhhhhhhhh no. (I mean yeah probably, but that's not what's going on -- this is homework). This is set intersection, _kind of_

Comment: sorry I wasn't very specific, as the number m is given, n should be compared to it, and for n = 3 (0003), there's 3 and 0 as same digits, and for n = 33 (0033), there's two 3's and one zero as same digits.

Comment: @Humberto what's the expected result of `compare_digits(3, 331)`?

Comment: well, the complete homework involves a little game, where a random number m is generated, and then the user inputs n and the code tells them how many digits are right, regardless of order.

Comment: @Humberto is this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_(board_game) ?

Comment: @AdamSmith it should be 2, even if n has 3 twice, there's only one 3 in m, and the zero

Comment: @AdamSmith actually, it is very similar, my professor mentioned this game in my classes, but I didn't understand the wikipedia page that well to implement anything to my code :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with set intersection:

```
from collections import Counter

def compare_digits(m, n):
    m_counts = Counter(str(m).zfill(4))
    n_counts = Counter(str(n).zfill(4))

    return sum(min(m_counts[k], n_counts[k]) for k in m_counts.keys() & n_counts.keys())

print(compare_digits(331, 3))  # 2
print(compare_digits(332, 33)) # 3
print(compare_digits(3, 331))  # 2
```

Comment: Wow, this worked wonderfully, BUT my prof haven't even teached us how to use for loops, let alone Counter and these functions inside the return command... He really want us to use basic stuff like while and if-else, and true-false statements

Comment: @Humberto What data structures has he taught you? lists? dictionaries?

Comment: none of these yet, it's an introductory class and he's only taught types, basic operations, while and if-elif-else loops, and operations like and-or, nothing more than this iirc

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to limit the number of digits to 4 and not be generic about it, so I wrote this and it worked perfectly:

```
def compare_digits(m, n):
a = m % 10
m //= 10
b = m % 10
m //= 10
c = m % 10
m //= 10
d = m % 10

read_ndigits = 0
same_digits = 0

while read_ndigits < 4:
    current = n % 10
    if current == a:
        same_digits += 1
        a = None
    elif current == b:
        same_digits += 1
        b = None
    elif current == c:
        same_digits += 1
        c = None
    elif current == d:
        same_digits += 1
        d = None
    n //= 10
    read_ndigits += 1

return same_digits
```

Thank you all for your help :)